# How do I get all O365 products plans using Microsoft Graph..Like E1, E2 etc

Tags: asp.net-mvc, microsoft-graph-api

I am new to Microsoft Graph and have already listed users of a tenant with their assigned plans. I searched through the documentation but could not get a endpoint to query for O365 Product Plans like E1,E2, E3 business etc.

Can anyone please guide me on how I can accomplish that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are looking to get a form of commerce API that can list the Microsoft cloud product catalog, I don't think this exists.  Please ask for this on [UserVoice](https://officespdev.uservoice.com/forums/224641-feature-requests-and-feedback/category/101632-microsoft-graph-o365-rest-apis).  If instead you wanted to know what subscriptions (and their details) that your tenant has you can use the `subscribedSkus` API [here](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/resources/subscribedsku)

Hope this helps,

Comment: Thank you Dan. Answers my question perfectly :-)